# "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Runtime"

Tags: c#, nodejs

estoy tratando de ejecutar una función que se encuentra dentro de una dll, en nodejs con la librería ffi-napi. pero me esta dando este error:

```
Excepción no controlada: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

Tengo el proyecto, pero no fue desarrollado por mi persona, y C# no es mi lenguaje nativo.

Cualquier sugerencia sería genial.

Nota: estoy desarrollando en windows 10